# LSB codename isn't a valid LM codename, cannot install Wine

Tags: linux-mint, wine

Just installed Linux Mint 19 Xfce yesterday and am now trying to get Wine installed but always the command  sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main' returns me

```
juillet@juillet-K73SJ ~ $ sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
LSB codename: 'tara'.
Version of base-files: '19.0.1'.
Your LSB codename isn't a valid Linux Mint codename.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".
```

I apply the commands prescribed here, but that does not change my situation.
Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

[Installing WineHQ packages](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I well placed the command

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

This command sends me

```
LSB code name: 'tara' 
Version of base-file: '19.0.1'
Your LSB codename isn't a valid Linux Mint codename.
Please check your LSB information with "lsb_release -a".
```

"lsb_release -a" send me back

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID :LinuxMint
Description:  Linux Mint 19 Tara
Release:      19
Codename:     Tara
```